# Extract certain string from other string

Tags: java, regex, string, extract

I made a project myself where I need to extract a certain string of a URL.
Before I used

```
Arrays.asList(URL.split("/")).get(6);
```

but with this I only can get it, if it is after the 6th **/**. 
I knew there is something with **matcher()** but I don't get it to work.

For example:

```
https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/SOMETEXTHERE/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1
```

I want to extract out the SOMETEXTHERE. But this characters are changing so I can't just say that it is always the same.
And I need the SOMETEXT then in a seperate string.

Comment: You have to define the rule before using matcher.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat but that i asked there is to replace the text...

Comment: @MrMinemeet I have retracted the close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group(1)` to retrive the text between `product/` and `/ref`:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*product/(.*)/ref.*");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/SOMETEXTHERE/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1");
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `(?<=/product/)[^/]+` would be better. With `matcher.find()` in place of `matcher.matches()` and `Syso(matcher.group(0))`